# Why there is a $(-1)$ factor in the cofactor - determinant relation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page $116$, section $4.14$, it says that

> Given an $n\times n$ matrix, $A = (\alpha_j^i)$, denote for each pair
>   $(i,j)$ by $S_i^j$ the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix obtained from A by
>   deleting the i-th row and the j-th column.We are going to show that 
>   $$cof (\alpha_i^j) = (-1)^{i+j} det S_i^j.$$
>
> In fact, by $(i-1)$ interchanges of rows and $(j-1)$ interchanges of
>   columns we can transform $C_i^j$ into the matrix
>
> [image]
>
> , where $C_i^j$ is
>
> [image]

So here is my question: Why do we need $(i-1)$ interchanges of rows or $(j-1)$ interchanges of columns. I mean can't we directly interchange the j-th column with the first column, and the i-th row with the first row ?

In this way, determinant would be changes its sign twice, which would give us the same determinant.

Comment: You want to preserve $S_i^j$. Switching rows and columns as you have done may switch the sign of $\det(S_i^j)$, depending on the parity of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: @MichaelLee Then how does interchanging $(i-1)$ rows not affect the sign of $det(S_i^j)$ ?

Comment: @MichaelLee I mean what is the difference between my method and the books method ?

Comment: You're not just interchanging $i-1$ rows. You're interchanging them in such a way that they remain in the same order while you extract the $i$th row.

Comment: @MichaelLee You are right, thanks. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to preserve $S_i^j$. By interchanging the $i$th row with the $(i-1)$th row, then the $(i-2)$th row, et cetera, you extract the $i$th row without changing the sign of $\det(S_i^j)$. The way of thinking about this that you have suggested accomplishes essentially the same thing in terms of extracting the $i$th row and $j$th column, but the determinant of the matrix you get is related to $\det(S_i^j)$ by the parity of $i$ and $j$ anyway.